# Child in a child shell page? - Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, navigation, hierarchy, flyout

I'm a beginner Xamarin developer and I would like to ask about Shells because I'm stuck.
For my first app, I would like to create a structure like this using Shell, but I've tried many different things and didn't succeed. I literally watched every single tutorial and I still can't understand.

For example, I would like to save some notes to a local database.

Structure:

```
LoginPage
ProfilePage
    NewProfilePage
NotePage
    NewNotePage
AboutUsPage
SettingsPage
```

I would like to do it with a flyout. Like there would be a sidebar list

- Profiles
- Notes
- About
- Settings

And if the user wants to create a note s/he just taps on Notes and there will be a "New Note" toolbar item that will go to the NewNotePage. What route should I use?

I've tried several methods like these:

```
<ShellItem Title="MyApp" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
    <ShellContent Route="ProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage}">
        <ShellContent Route="NewProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewProfilePage}"/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Route="NotePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NotePage}">
        <ShellContent Route="NewNotePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewNotePage}"/>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Route="ContactPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ContactPage}"/>
    <ShellContent Route="SettingsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
```

.

```
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</ShellItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="New Profile" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" Route="NewProfilePage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewProfilePage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="ProfilePage" Route="ProfilePage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfilePage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="NotePage" Route="NotePage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NotePage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="NewNotePage" Route="NewNotePage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StatsPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="ContactPage" Route="ContactPage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ContactPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="SettingsPage" Route="SettingsPage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Could you please focus and highlight the issues you are having? what is working and what's not working or missing so far?

Comment: I think I've solved the problem. The second code actually works for me. I just removed the NewNotePage and added as a registrated route at the beginning, but thank you.

Comment: Good thing you are trying a lot yourself. My advice would be to stop using shell, you basically run into problems really quick that get solved really easily by using MVVM. Secondly I would maybe start using MAUI, since it's the replacement for Xamarin.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer I strongly believe that It is a very bad advice to start using MAUI for a beginner or for real app because it's still in early stage preview/unstable versions, there is no extensive documentation and last but not least the basics are same (such xaml..) so better to start learning with a stable framework ie: Xamarin.

Comment: @Cfun I dissagree. Xamarin itself is riddled with bugs (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180471/why-is-xamarin-so-full-of-bugs-even-after-almost-a-decade-of-development) and has experienced an exodus from people leaving to better platforms e.g. Flutter or even native development. Using Shell is even worse than Xamarin at this point. Trying to do anything remotely custom will automatically transition you back to Xamarin with an MVVM approach. In this case from routing in shell to indexing and deep linking in Xamarin.

Comment: As for the usage of MAUI. I tend to agree to not immediately start using the new products that come out. However, in this case the alternative is the same but the implementation is worse. At least with MAUI he'll be able to get things done, also cross platform much more easily. Also the techniques employed are new but widely accepted in the development communitiy e.g. MVU. You also mention XAML being the same. Therefore I would not linger in the Xamarin ecosystem but transition to MAUI since the basics are essentially the same, but you are also future proof.